# Making canvas background as XML layout

Tags: android

I have an XML layout. I want to draw a line after getting the button clicked. I made an inner class to accomplish it. But when it do so my content view get changed to canvas of `View` class.
I want my content view to be the same XML with the line I generated by clicking a `Button`.
Thank you.

Code:

```
public class Dots extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener   
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dots);

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                b[i][j] = (Button) findViewById(refbutton[i][j]);
                b[i][j].setOnClickListener(this);
            }
        }   
    }

    private static class SampleView extends View
    {              
        public SampleView(Context context)
        {
            super(context);
        }

        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
        {
             Paint p = new Paint();
             p.setColor(Color.BLACK);
             p.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

             canvas.drawLine(5, 5, 25, 5, p);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.dots, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SampleView d=new SampleView(this);
        setContentView(d);   
    }
}
```

Comment: Provide some code to explain what you mean

Comment: @Lunchbox .here is my code ..hope to get some help